# scope variable undefined in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with directive i want use scope variable inside directive but it is throwing undefined error.

i want to loop with fixed number? so i amtring   
here items is undefined error i am getting ?

is there any other way to iterrate loop particular no. of times ??

**HTML:**

```
<my-dir 
        bgcolor="#EFF"
        my-title="abdullah" 
        my-height="190"
        my-width="160"
        my-color="red"            
        my-bgcolor="blue"
        my-collapseoption=true
        my-widgetno="1"
        save="saveChanges('custom directive')">template
      </my-dir>
```

**Script:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',  ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.items = ['a','b','c'];
    });

// add a directive
app.directive("myDir", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      items:"=",
      myTitle: "@",   // by value
      myHeight: "@",   // by value
      myWidth: "@",   // by value
      myColor: "@",   // by value
      myBgcolor: "@",   // by value
      myWidgetno: "@", // by reference
      myCollapseoption: "@", // by reference            
      save: "&"    // event
    },

    templateUrl:"widget.html", 

    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        // show initial values: by-val members will be undefined
       console.log("items is " +scope.items);


        // change element just to show we can
        element.css("background", attrs.myBgcolor);
        element.css("color", attrs.myColor);
        element.css("width", attrs.myWidth+'px');
       // element.css("height", attrs.myHeight+'px');

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: can you show the HTML fragment where you call this directive?

Comment: @AndrewCounts updated Question please check

Comment: Are you sure your HTML is correct? I don't see you add items="" in your HTML. Could you make sure your example code is correct? If it is, then the solution is to pass items attribute to your <my-dir> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You never passed your items property to the directive, so it is definitely going to be undefined when the directive attempts to access it.  Your my-dir tag needs to provide the attribute.  Try:

```
<my-dir 
    items={{items}}
.... />
```

Comment: $scope.items = ['a','b','c']; cant i use controller  $scope.items = ['a','b','c']; inside directive?

Comment: the directive does not have access to $scope or other controllers once you use isolation.  The entire point of isolation is to ensure that the directive is able to operate on variables independent of what other directives, controllers, etc. are doing.  If you don't pass the variable to the directive, it doesn't have access to it.

Comment: also, and most importantly, scope IS NOT $scope